# Running multiple Maven instances of a framework, how to set the goals?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

Framework is run from a root directory typing

```
mvn ninja:run
```

To run two or more instances of Maven, I have to use modules.  I got that part as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <modules>
        <module>/user</module>
        <module>/admin</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

To run on a specified port, I would have to type

```
mvn ninja:run -Dninja.port=YourPortNumber
```

what changes do I need to add to a pom.xml file and where, to get the both instances running at the same time and on different ports?

Edit: Ideal solution would be typing just a simple "mvn" command to start the modules which would make both instance run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [Ninja Plugin](http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/basic_concepts/super_dev_mode.html), you can configure the port as part of the plugin configuration as well, not only via command line option (the `-Dninja.port=YourPortNumber` option you mentioned).

Hence, in your two sub-modules, you could configure the plugin as following:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.ninjaframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>ninja-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>1234</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As part of the `port` section, you can then type in each of the sub-module the specific port number you want to use and not providing it anymore from the command line. Also note, in the snippet above I used the 5.2.2 version (the latest), but you can change it according to the version you meant to use. Further note: you may already have a `build` section as part of your POM, in that case you would only need to add the `plugin` section above to the existing list of `plugins` configurations, if any.

As such, you would only require to execute `mvn ninja:run`, port numbers will be provided by each sub-module configuration.

Side note: it should be clear that Maven is a build tool and not an executor tool (even though it is a plugin executor in its bones), so we cannot pretend to simply launch `mvn` and execute our own logic.

Comment: A really good answer, thank you !!! Since Maven is a build tool, does it mean that I have to build either a jar or a war for each of the projects, with the mentioned port number configurations, and then run them both with some other utility? If so, what should I build the project to (jar or war?) and what should I use to run them both once they are compiled ?

Comment: that would probably be the best approach, however keep in mind that the configuration provided in the POM would then not be used by the built jar/war unless you provide it via further configuration. I will need to look at this framework and plugin to understand it better. As an example: you can run a Java webapp from Maven using the Jetty Plugin as embedded web server for tests, but then you build your web app as a WAR and deploy it in a effectively running web server (i.e. Tomcat) and test it on that as a final/target environment. So you use maven to test it, to build it, not to run it.

Comment: I was thinking about Tomcat too. They got a plenty information here: http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/deployment.html